# Granting write permission on www-data for /var/www/[username]

Tags: 14.04, permissions, apache2, php, error-handling

I am new to this www-data concept, please do explain in simple words. I have a directory in the path `/var/www/orbitcode`. I want `orbitcode` to have www-data write permission. How to do this? I am probably doing this because of White screen Of Death, as my index.php is showing blank

Comment: I am sorry but i did not quite get the answer by referring to the link.

Comment: The apache2 version that was published when the Ubuntu 14.04 release was made is 2.4.7 and starting with this version it seems that, for security reasons, the new root directory for the server is: `/var/www/html` instead of the old `/var/www` which you can still find online in some obsolete tutorials.